# How can I use an if statement to check if a number only has two digits after the decimal in java?

Tags: java, numbers

I'm currently only checking to see if a number is a float using this

```
public boolean checkStringFloat(String str) {
    try{
        Float.parseFloat(str);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

but I want to use an if statement to check if it is a decimal with two digits.
So for instance numbers like: 6.24, 5.28,13242.31, would be allowed
but numbers like: 5.234, 1, 0, 4.235 would not be allowed.
How can I do this?

Comment: First of all, float and double are _not_ exact types, meaning that speaking of the "number" of digits after the decimal point is not a well defined thing.  If you want to proceed on this path, you need an exact type such as `BigDecimal`.

Comment: You have it as a String. Just split this String using the dot and then count the length of the index 1 of the splitted array.

Comment: What about `"13242.310"`?

Answer (score 2):

Split the string, and check the length of second part.

```
"13242.31".split( "\\." )[ 1 ].length() == 2
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/iW9YP6).

```java
boolean hasTwoDigitDecimalFraction = "13242.31".split( "\\." )[ 1 ].length() == 2 ;
System.out.println( hasTwoDigitDecimalFraction ) ;
```

> true

Validate your inputs by calling [`String#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) to be sure it has a FULL STOP character. And check the length of the array from the `.split` to be sure it has exactly two elements.

Be aware that in many parts of the world such inputs would use a COMMA rather than a FULL STOP character as the delimiter: `13242,31`.

Answer (score 1):

## `BigDecimal#scale`

As @TimBiegeleisen said, use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) with its [`scale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#scale()) method.

```java
public boolean checkStringFloat(String str) {
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(str);
    if(bigDecimal.scale() == 2) {
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My general idea is as follows, just for reference
Start with a simple end-to-zero operation on the string
String indexOf('.') returns i, len= string.length and the following will happen:

1. i=-1 , it means that there is no decimal point
2. i=len-2 , There are two characters after the decimal point, so you only need to determine whether the two characters is a number
3. i>=len || i<len-2 Obviously, not

Answer (score 0):

You could find the length of the string after the "." using `.substring()`.

```java
if (str.substring(str.indexOf(".")).length() == 2) return true;
else return false;
```

I don't have an editor with me, but this should work fine. If it doesn't, try adding a 1 to the indexOf.